where is problem with refreshing in my android app
I'm new to Kotlin and wrote this code for a university assignment(this is the first time when I used it and probably the last one), but I'm facing an issue where the main screen doesn't refresh as expected. I'm using Android Studio to build the app. When I click the button, the text in the middle and the colors of the buttons should be changed but they dont.
package com.example.maze_lab

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.MutableState
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.example.maze_lab.ui.theme.Maze_labTheme

data class Position(var posRow: Int, var posCol: Int)

var  mapRowSize = 4
var  mapColSize = 4

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {



    val roomsArray = arrayOf(
        arrayOf(10, 8, 10, 9),
        arrayOf(28, 1, 0, 12),
        arrayOf(12, 10, 9, 13),
        arrayOf(6, 5, 6, 5)
    )

    val roomMovementOption = arrayOf(
        arrayOf(arrayOf(0,0,0,0), arrayOf(0,0,0,0), arrayOf(0,0,0,0), arrayOf(0,0,0,0)),
        arrayOf(arrayOf(0,0,0,0), arrayOf(0,0,0,0), arrayOf(0,0,0,0), arrayOf(0,0,0,0)),
        arrayOf(arrayOf(0,0,0,0), arrayOf(0,0,0,0), arrayOf(0,0,0,0), arrayOf(0,0,0,0)),
        arrayOf(arrayOf(0,0,0,0), arrayOf(0,0,0,0), arrayOf(0,0,0,0), arrayOf(0,0,0,0))
    )

    val playerPos = mutableStateOf<Position>(Position(0,0))

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        calculateBitsToMoves(roomsArray, roomMovementOption)
        findStartPos(roomsArray, playerPos)

        for(row in roomsArray.indices) {
            for (col in roomsArray[row].indices) {
                roomMovementOption[row][col][3] = if ((roomsArray[row][col] and 0b0001) != 0) 1 else 0 //left
                roomMovementOption[row][col][2] = if ((roomsArray[row][col] and 0b0010) != 0) 1 else 0 //right
                roomMovementOption[row][col][1] = if ((roomsArray[row][col] and 0b0100) != 0) 1 else 0 //top
                roomMovementOption[row][col][0] = if ((roomsArray[row][col] and 0b1000) != 0) 1 else 0 //down
                Log.i(
                    "movementOption",
                    "${roomMovementOption[row][col][0]} ${roomMovementOption[row][col][1]} ${roomMovementOption[row][col][2]} ${roomMovementOption[row][col][3]}"
                )
            }
        }

        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            Maze_labTheme {
                Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background)
                {
                    RenderBoard(
                        movementOption = roomMovementOption,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
                        position = playerPos,
                    )
                    Log.i("UpdatePos", "row: ${playerPos.value.posRow}, col: ${playerPos.value.posCol}")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fun calculateBitsToMoves(
    values: Array<Array<Int>>,
    movment: Array<Array<Array<Int>>>
) {
    for(row in values.indices) {
        for (col in values[row].indices) {
            movment[row][col][3] = if ((values[row][col] and 0b0001) != 0) 1 else 0 //left
            movment[row][col][2] = if ((values[row][col] and 0b0010) != 0) 1 else 0 //right
            movment[row][col][1] = if ((values[row][col] and 0b0100) != 0) 1 else 0 //top
            movment[row][col][0] = if ((values[row][col] and 0b1000) != 0) 1 else 0 //down
        }
    }
}

fun findStartPos(values: Array<Array<Int>>, position: MutableState<Position>)
{
    for(row in values.indices)
    {
        for(col in values[row].indices)
        {
            if ((values[row][col] and 0b10000) != 0)
            {
                position.value.posCol = col
                position.value.posRow = row
                Log.i("PosOfPlayer", "row: ${position.value.posRow}, col: ${position.value.posCol}")
                break
            }
        }
    }
}


fun UpdatePos(position: MutableState<Position>, posRow:Int, posCol:Int)
{
    position.value.posRow = position.value.posRow + posRow
    position.value.posCol = position.value.posCol + posCol

    if(position.value.posRow < 0)
    {
        position.value.posRow = mapRowSize - 1
    }
    else if(position.value.posRow > mapRowSize-1)
    {
        position.value.posRow = 0
    }

    if(position.value.posCol < 0)
    {
        position.value.posCol = mapColSize - 1
    }
    else if(position.value.posCol > mapColSize-1)
    {
        position.value.posCol = 0
    }
}

@Composable
fun RenderBoard(position: MutableState<Position>,
                movementOption: Array<Array<Array<Int>>>,
                modifier: Modifier = Modifier
)
{
    var testtest = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    Log.i("Ja pierdole", "Czy to w ogole działa?")
    Column(modifier = modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
        val rows = 3
        val cols = 3

        for (row in 0 until rows) {
            Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly) {
                for (col in 0 until cols) {
                    when {
                        (row == 1 && col == 1) -> {
                            // "x" - Display text with row and column
                            Text(
                                text = "Row: ${position.value.posRow}, Col: ${position.value.posCol}",
                                modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)
                            )
                        }
                        (row == 0 && col == 1) -> { //up
                            val bgColor = if (movementOption[position.value.posRow][position.value.posCol][1] == 1) {
                                Color.Green
                            } else {
                                Color.Red
                            }

                            Button(

                                onClick = {
                                    UpdatePos(position = position, posRow = 1, posCol = 1)
                                },
                                modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp).background(bgColor)
                            ) {
                                Text(text ="Up")
                            }
                        }

                        (row == 1 && col == 0) -> { //Left
                            val bgColor = if (movementOption[position.value.posRow][position.value.posCol][3] == 1) {
                                Color.Green
                            } else {
                                Color.Red
                            }

                            Button(

                                onClick = {
                                    UpdatePos(position = position, posRow = 1, posCol = 1)
                                },
                                modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp).background(bgColor)
                            ) {
                                Text(text ="Left")
                            }
                        }

                        (row == 1 && col == 2) -> { //Right
                            val bgColor = if (movementOption[position.value.posRow][position.value.posCol][2] == 1) {
                                Color.Green
                            } else {
                                Color.Red
                            }

                            Button(
                                onClick = {
                                    UpdatePos(position = position, posRow = 1, posCol = 1)
                                },
                                modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp).background(bgColor)
                            ) {
                                Text(text ="Right")
                            }
                        }

                        (row == 2 && col == 1) -> { //Down
                            val bgColor = if (movementOption[position.value.posRow][position.value.posCol][0] == 1) {
                                Color.Green
                            } else {
                                Color.Red
                            }

                            Button(
                                onClick = {
                                    UpdatePos(position = position, posRow = 1, posCol = 1)
                                },
                                modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp).background(bgColor)
                            ) {
                                Text(text ="Down")
                            }
                        }
                        else -> {
                            // "i" - Empty space
                            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(50.dp))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Please look into creating a [mre] (emphasis on minimal) for your problem before asking for help here.
